# How to pass props/state through Link and Route - react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm in the middle of creating my first web app made with react.js (create-react-app and react-router 3.0.2, no redux) and i've encountered a problem with passing a property through the Link and Route (i'm not sure if what i'm trying to do is a correct approach in "react way" of making an app)

Idea is that AddCost component (which im not pasting since it's irrelevant) should render a little bit different depending on a property passed onto it. However i'm not sure how to do it (and if it's even possible that way)

Index.js is the main rendering component, App.js is the main container and div with className='content' is where i want to {Home} and {AddCost} to render interchangeably (when i clink on one of the links in {Home} i want to {AddCost} render in the same place as {Home} was rendered before (and that works) but i cant get to pass a prop to the {AddCost} component depending on which of the links i click)

So the main questions is as in title, how to pass information from {Home} to {AddCost} when react-router is used for routing?

```js
//Index.js

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './components/App'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Stats from './components/Stats'
import Account from './components/Account'
import AddCost from './components/AddCost'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path="/AddCost" component={() => (<AddCost costType="value" />)}/>
      <Route path="/stats" component={Stats} />
      <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

//App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Header from './Header'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      costType: null
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
          <Header />
          <div className="content">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App

//Home.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import './Home.css'

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    const costTypes = [
      { text: 'Health', icon: 'fa fa-heart' },
      { text: 'Bills', icon: 'fa fa-home' },
      { text: 'Gas', icon: 'fa fa-car' },
      { text: 'Vacation', icon: 'fa fa-plane' },
      { text: 'Lunch', icon: 'fa fa-coffee' },
      { text: 'Groceries', icon: 'fa fa-shopping-cart' },
      { text: 'Leisure', icon: 'fa fa-glass' },
      { text: 'Leisure', icon: 'fa fa-glass' },
    ]
    const listItems = costTypes.map((type, i) => (
      <Link key={i} className='cost__element' to='/addcost'>
        <i className={type.icon} aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h1>{type.text}</h1>
      </Link>
    ))
    return (
      <section className='home'>
        <ul className='costList'>{listItems}</ul>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default Home
```

Additionally i'll gladly accept information about any major mistakes or bad practice examples.

Comment: You should post this to Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Stack Overflow is for getting answers to programming questions, not for getting advice on how to improve your code.

Comment: I'm aware of the CE however code which i provided doesnt work so im actually asking a programming question which is how to pass a prop through the LINK and Route. I've thought about the CE aswell but it seemed to me as only working code should be posted there.

Comment: Ah, OK, I didn't realize this from your post. Then please an actual question to your post (I didn't find any), and the error messages you're getting.

Comment: Ok, i've edited my post a little bit, so that its more clear what exactly is my question, however im not pasting any error messages since im not getting any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options here. One of them is to use route params.

1) First you need to change `path` attribute of your route

```js
<Route path="addcost/:type" component={AddCost} />
```

2) Inside your `AddCost` comonent you can get type as `this.props.params.type` and decide what to render

```js
class AddCost extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.params.type)
  }
}
```

3) Finaly use another `to` attribute in your links

```js
<Link to="addcost/foo" />
<Link to="addcost/bar" />
```

Comment: Great, works exactly as i intended. Ive found that solution before, however not sure why but i thought that `<Route path="addcost/:type" component={AddCost} />` means that i have to generate amount of Route elements that is equal to the number of Link with different paths. Seems i was wrong. Thank you.